# Immutable JS - getIn() returns undefined but works in console from the browser

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, immutable.js

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
this.state = {
      data: Immutable.Map({
        gender: "",
        provinces: Immutable.Map(),
        activeProvince: this.props.defaultProvince,
        activeCity: this.props.defaultCity,
      })
    }


let cities = this.state.data.getIn(['provinces', '354']);


The structure would look like this:

state{

  gender: "",
  activeProvince: "354",
  provinces: { 
    354: { 
      name: "abc",
      cities: Immutable.Map()
    }, 

    123: { 
      name: "def", 
      cities: Immutable.Map() 
    }
}
```

getting the 'provinces' only returns a Map with a size of 87 which means it has value, but going 1 level deeper gives me an undefined. Doing it in the console from the browser gives me the expected result.

I am doing it from the render() right before the "return"

```
render(){

    let provinces = this.state.data.get('provinces')
      .sortBy( province => province.get('name') )
      .map( (value, key) => {
        return { text: value.get('name'), value: key }
      });

    // Supposed to do the same thing as above (provinces)
    // with ['provinces'] only it returns a value, adding '354' returns undefined.
    let cities = this.state.data.getIn(['provinces', '354']);

    console.log(cities);
```

-- EDIT --

converting the provinces Map to an object by doing 'toObject()' shows the key exists, so why does getIn('provinces,'354') shows undefined?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to reproduce your problem, I notice that `provinces` key and its one level children are immutable, but `name` and `cities` keys are actually mutable. That's why, I'm getting error on the line containing `sortBy`function. To solve this, you need to define `provinces` with `Immutable.fromJS()` instead of `Immutable.Map()`. `Immutable.Map()` converts object to immutable for only one level. However, `Immutable.fromJS()`, converts all levels to immutable.

Comment: It's actually Immutable. I just showed what it looked like. Got it working now. I'm having an error that causes render to stop because of the initial province state is empty.